# Silverlight 4 DataGrid Column

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a bit 'stupid' question, but I can't figure it out. I need this column in my DataGrid:
[image: Column marked by red arrow is needed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `DataGridRowHeader`. Try to set `HeadersVisibility` property to `All` or `Row` in you `DataGrid`.